# The storage space isn't decreased after deleting doc from Db. Why?

Tags: mongodb

I have deleted the documents of the collection by running deleteMany query on the shell and it returned acknowledged true and result.

Even after deleting around 1 million documents the size of the db is same while running show dbs command.

The delete query which I have executed on the shell:

```
db.getCollection('activity').deleteMany({createdAt:{$lte: 1565375400000}})
```

The result of the above query is:

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 1199713 }
```

Before and after the query the output of show dbs command is:

```
admin           0.000GB
local           0.000GB
logDb          17.203GB
```

Why is it so that db size isn't decreased and what can I do to free that size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im going to explain in short:

**why is it happening**
by inspecting the db with db.stats() you will realize that mongoDB has storageSize(data +unused space) and dataSize(data in the db). if you delete documents from your database, you are actually decreasing the dataSize. this is because mongodb follows a storage policy that I can call 'take all you can, give nothing back'. say you had 15GB of data and you delete 5GB, MongoDB will keep holding on to the entire 15 GB disk space it had before, so it can use that same space to store new data later.

**how do i free the storage**

In case you are in a **development environment** I would suggest to dump the database, drop it and then restore it.
1.  this is how you create a backup: 
       https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/
2.drop the database by executing in mongo shell:

```
 db.dropDatabase()
```

and then mongorestore (this is the link to documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/)

Answer (score 6):

MongoDB will not release the space back to disk. Instead, it'll reserve the space considering the future growth

The right way to run an housekeeping is by dropping unwanted collections or drop unwanted DB's (make sure to take backup) which would release the space back to OS

As you've already deleted the docs, I would suggest you to run the compact command during  maintenance window (if its a critical environment) which will defrag all the data and indexes and release the space back to OS

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

from the version of mongodb 3.4.0+, just use "compact" , like as:

db.runCommand({compact:})

here is the document: [https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.4/faq/storage/](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/faq/storage/)

> How do I reclaim disk space in WiredTiger?
> The WiredTiger storage engine maintains lists of empty records in data files as it deletes documents. This space can be reused by WiredTiger, but will not be returned to the operating system unless under very specific circumstances.

> The amount of empty space available for reuse by WiredTiger is reflected in the output of db.collection.stats() under the heading wiredTiger.block-manager.file bytes available for reuse.

> To allow the WiredTiger storage engine to release this empty space to the operating system, you can de-fragment your data file. This can be achieved using the compact command. For more information on its behavior and other considerations, see compact.

Comment: Note that before version 4.4 compact is a blocking operation.
Rant warning! The strategy of not returning disk space to the OS regardless the circumstances is simply ridiculous. We have had collections with almost 1TB of "file bytes available for reuse" while mongo crashed due to running out of space on disk. Brilliant?!?!